# why does net.connect in nodejs sometimes take so long to invoke callback?

Tags: javascript, node.js, sockets, nwjs

I have the following nodejs code using `net.connect` in my `nwjs` app:

```
const client = net.connect({ host: '127.0.0.1', port }, () => {
  log.debug("inside the net.connect method")

  client.write(JSON.stringify(payload) + '\r\n')
  client.end()
})
```

I have watched this code execute in wireshark -- and it makes the connection to the server almost immediately, however sometimes it doesn't actually write the payload until 5 seconds later.

I have added logging statements and see that the callback isn't even executed until up to 5 seconds later.

Why is it doing this? and how might i debug it and fix it? I obviously want the callback to execute as quickly as possible -- soon after the actual connection is established!

EDIT: when it does take a while, it is almost invariably 5 seconds. Is this some kind of timeout?

Comment: Do you have the same delay in node or just in nwjs?